# Good Django design practice to add a REST api later following DRY

Tags: django, rest, dry

I am starting a web application in pure Django. However, in the future, there might be a requirement for REST api. If it happens, the most obvious choice will be Django REST framework.

Both the "old-fashioned" and REST parts share the models, however, the views are slightly different (permissions definitions, for example) and forms are replaced with serializers. Doing it the most obvious way would mean to duplicate the application logic several times, and thus a failure to follow DRY principle, and so the code becomes unmaintainable.

I got an idea to write all the logic into models (since they are shared), but in such case, there will be no use of permission mixins, generic views and the code would not be among the nicest ones.

Now I ran out of ideas. What is the best practice here?

Answer (score 3):

I'd try to keep things simple as you're not sure about the future requirements for the API, and guessing can introduce extra complexity that may not even be needed when requirements will be clear.

Both Django forms and Rest Framework serializers already offer you a declarative approach that abstracts away the boilerplate code needed for basic stuff, which normally accounts for most of your code anyway.
For example, one of your Django form could look like this:

```
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'content']
```

And in the future the DRS serializer would be:

```
class ArticleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title', 'content']
```

As you can see, if you try and stick to ModelForm and ModelSerializer, there won't be much duplication anyway. You can also simply store the fields list in a variable and just reuse that.

For more custom things, you can start by sharing logic into simple functions, for example:

```
def save_article_with_author(article_data, author_data):
    # custom data manipulation before saving, consider that article_data will be a dictionary either if it comes from deserialized JSON (api) or POST data
    # send email, whatever
```

This function can be shared between your form and serializer.

For everything related to data fetching, I'd try to use Model Managers as much as possible, defining custom querysets that can be resued e.g. for options by forms and serializers.

I tend to avoid writing any logic that doesn't directly read or write data into the model classes. I think that couples too much the business logic with the data layer. As an example, I never want to write any auth/permission checks into a save() method of a model, because that couples different layers too tightly.

As a rule of thumb, imagine this scenario: you add say permissions checks or the logic to send an email when a user is created overriding the save() method of your Article model. 
Then, later on you're asked to write a simple manage command that batch-import users from a spreadsheet. At this point, what you did in your save() method really gets in the way, as you can freely access your data through your model without having to bother with permissions, emails and all of that.

Regarding the view layer and assuming you need to implement some shared auth/permission checks and you don't want to have separate views, you can use this approach:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/

> Blockquote
>   REST framework is suitable for returning both API style responses, and regular HTML pages. Additionally, serializers can be used as HTML forms and rendered in templates.

Here's some guidelines on how you could dynamically switch from HTML to JSON based to the request content type:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#advanced-renderer-usage

This seems like a good option in your situation, I'd just write down a quick proof-of-concept before you go all in to see if you are not too limited for what you need to do.

Comment: I would just say 'thanks', but SO advises me not to do so :). I have some questions. How do I handle permissions? I find the approaches in pure Django and DRF a bit different (mixins vs permission classes), do I still make completely separate views in Django and DRF or is there a way how to "inject" one into another? And pretty much the same problem will occur when it comes to `ListView` vs `ListAPIView`, do I again need to create both of those?

Comment: @karlosss no problem, check out my last edit. With DRS views you can render HTML templates and use serializers as forms

Comment: Seems I know enough at the moment. If I don't forget it, I'll let you know how things went.